# How to do implementation of Tab Bar with slider out in IOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbar, tabslideout

I am building an IOS application where I want to add tab bar with slide out. I search a lot but not found any thing use full. I am new in IOS can please some share a blog of any tutorial that help me in solution this problem. Please help.

Comment: Would you like to add slider in tab bar?

Comment: yes.. @NileshPatel can you please help me. But I want that slider on all of three tab bar view

Comment: Clear one more doubt like, Would you like to add scrollview kind of thing in Tabbar? OR You would like to integrate slide menu in controller & want tab bar to slide when side menu get opened??

Comment: I want excitedly same as this google map app dose here is itune link - https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/google-maps/id585027354?mt=8

Comment: @hiteshmatnani you succesed to implement it ?